# For what reason browser side XSLT is not widely used by web-developers?

Tags: xml, xslt, browser

I have personally discovered the technique that delivers XML and XSL to browser separately and then performs XSLT on client side over 10 years ago.
To those, who don't aware there's a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='index.xsl'?>
<page xmlns="http://softsky.com.ua" language="en">
  <title>SOFTSKY - Information Security Audit</title>
</page>
```

and XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
   version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-us" class="no-js">      
      <head>                
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="/page/title"/></title>
</head>
</html>
```

would do the job.

Those time only limited set of browsers supported it, but technique was just amazing. Client will cache loaded XSL and automatic data binding will be performed so browser just need to update XML all the time. XML could even contain internationalized text for multilanguage support. I've recently tried pretty simple XSLT on dozed browsers using BrowserStack and it looks that it's widely supported. Even on mobile.

I'm in software development for 20+ years but never saw any framework that use that technique. What's the reason?

Comment: I'm afraid that StackOverflow doesn't really encourage that kind of question: the site tries to focus very strictly on solving coding problems, so musings on why some technologies are more successful than others are out of scope, however fascinating. A better place for such deeper discussions is the xsl-list hosted at mulberrytech.com - which is rather quiet nowadays, as SO has taken over much of its function, but it's still inhabited by many people who like to think about XSLT more strategically.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay, I'll consider putting my question to xsl-list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not just a good question, but rather an ***excellent* question**.

The combination of `XSLT + XML` = `(X)HTML` is **IMHO** the **absolutely best** way of creating a website.

Its power is tremendous. I do create my own websites in this way and so I'm a *real website programmer* (because XSLT is a *turing complete programming language*!).

I remember having read that one famous website is/was using this technique:
[blizzard.com](http://blizzard.com), the creators on *World of Warcraft* et al. I can neither confirm nor deny this.

As a developer myself, I can confirm that this development choice is possible. You can create a (very good) website with `XSLT+XML=(X)HTML`.

And more than that: **This (development) path is premium!**

So relating to your question: "why is this not standard"?

> I guess that it's not, because *all actions* are done client-side and so are not trackable and are of no use for (fucking) big-data-companies.

That's the main reason, I guess:
Technically perfect, but monetary deficient.

Comment: What actions do you mean? :) All needed actions could still be tracked by javascript and XML accessed on server side...

Comment: @Archer: That's a really good question. But the answer is **NO**. In a good XSLT+XML implementation there are three files to be downloaded from the webserver: _XSLT, XML, CSS._ After that, (nearly) everything can be processed _Client-Side_. That's the advantage (and main disadvantage for Big-Data) of this approach. And probably the main reason it is marginalized. If you manage to route the 'clicks' to your local-copy of your website, no internet access/AJAX is necessary at all for creating a whole new view of the XML content being displayed as HTML.

Comment: The XSLT+XML approach saves significant money, because you can cleanly separate the frontend HTML+CSS and the backend XML across separate teams, and avoid the need for rare full stack developers. You can also keep the skin of a website completely separate from backend.